# Error in If-Else statement for Apple Script to resurface 1 year old notes

Tags: if-statement, applescript

I'm trying to create an Apple Script that resurfaces a note from a year ago.

This is my code thus far:

```
set today to current date
set day of today to 1
set time of today to 0
set throwback to today - (365 * days)
tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Notes"
            if exists (note whose creation date is throwback) then
                show (every note whose creation date is throwback)
            else
                display dialog "No notes from this day a year ago, check back in tomorrow!"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I keep getting a script error that states "Can’t get note whose creation date = date "Monday, February 1, 2021 at 12:00:00 AM"."

But in the case that it cannot get a note, I'd like it to display the dialog written in the code above. When the if statement fails why does it not go through with the else statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for multiple notes (plural)

```
if exists (notes whose creation date is throwback) then
```